# Python: does calling a method 'directly' instantiate the object?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and while unit testing some methods on my object I noticed something 'weird'.

```
class Ape(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'ooook'

    def say(self, s):
        print s

def main():
    Ape().say('eeek')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I wrote this little example to illustrate where I got confused. If you do Ape().say('eeek') does this actually instantiate an Ape object and run the init method? I thought it wouldn't but I had some weird side effects so now I am thinking it does?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it does. That's what `Ape()` does: it creates an new `Ape` object, and as part of that process the `__init__` method gets run.

In your example, you then call the `say` method of that object. Note that there would be no way to call `say` if you didn't have an `Ape` object.

Comment: Thanks that clears things up. I guess Ape() gets garbaged collected right away since there is no reference to it anywhere?

Comment: @Pickels: it becomes inaccessible right away, so it _could_ be garbage collected immediately, yes. Or it might stick around in the nether void of unreachable memory until the Python interpreter decides it wants to reclaim the space ;-)

Answer (score 14):

If you want to call a method directly without creating an instance you can use the `staticmethod` decorator. Notice that there is no `self` when you use a static method

```
class Ape(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'ooook'

    @staticmethod
    def say(s):
        print s

def main():
    Ape.say('eeek')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Compare with class methods where the class is the first parameter instead of an instance

```
class Ape(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'ooook'

    @classmethod
    def say(cls, s):
        print "the class is:", cls
        print s

def main():
    Ape.say('eeek')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The class information part was extremely useful thanks. One thing to note though is that the init method is not run in either because it's not instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Ape() instantiates an object of class Ape, although since there is no assignment, no label is associated with it.  At this point its `__init__` function is called. Then, the say function is called.

To be clear:

```
Ape().say('eeek')
```

is equivalent to:

```
(Ape()).say('eeek')
```

Which more clearly indicates what happens first.