# Calling a Method in Python more Efficiently

Tags: python, unit-testing, methods, nosetests

I'm a newb working through Learn Python the Hard Way.

The point of this exercise is to write a word scanner for that passes the nosetests when run by a provided unit test.

While running nosetests on the following provided unit test I was getting this error:

`TypeError: unbound method scan() must be called with lexicon instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

**Lesson-supplied Test**

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex48 import lexicon

def test_directions():
    assert_equal(lex.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
    result = lex.scan("north south east")
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                          ('direction', 'south'),
                          ('direction', 'east)])
```

After some investigation I found here a user who is working through the same exercise:

[nosetests, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627528/nosetests-python)

[python variables, classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601080/python-variables-classes)

The answer there suggested instantiating (instaniating?) the method inside the unit test. So I did the following modification and wrote up my class in file ex48.py and it passes nosetests.

**Modified Test**

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex48 import lexicon


def test_directions():
    lex = lexicon("north")
    assert_equal(lex.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
    lex = lexicon("north south east")
    result = lex.scan("north south east")
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                          ('direction', 'south'),
                          ('direction', 'east')])
```

**ex48.py - Scanner**

```
class lexicon(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        #nosetests fails me if I don't put in some dummy
        # __init__ function with a dummy line, not sure why.
    self.direction = data

    def scan(self, data):
        split_data = data.split()
        directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
        data_reply = []
        #for loop for the length of the list
        for split_data_item in split_data:
            #If data is in the directions list
            if split_data_item in directions:
                #Add [('direction', data)] to a dict
                data_reply.append(('direction', split_data_item))

        #Return the list
        return data_reply
```

I'm not sure if the unit test was meant to be changed. I found a clue about 'directly intantiating an object' here:

[Python: does calling a method 'directly' instantiate the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200309/python-does-calling-a-method-directly-instantiate-the-object)

But am not sure if this applies. Can a scanner be made to instantiate itself or is the provided unit test a trick 'question' and must be modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep the test the way it was, and use a `@staticmethod` decorator on the scan method. This way, you'll be able to call the method directly from the class without need to instanciate an object for this.

```
class lexicon(object):

   @staticmethod
   def scan(data):
      #do the stuff here
```

Comment: This worked with a little modification: `def scan(data):` Thanks much. :)

Answer (score 4):

In the online version of [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html) they have:

```
def test_directions():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
    result = lexicon.scan("north south east")
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                          ('direction', 'south'),
                          ('direction', 'east')])
```

for the test, which suggests that you don't need a lexicon class, but a lexicon.py file with a scan function to test.

And it's spelled instantiating (as in I'm making an instance of this class).

Comment: Ah yes, my bad there, I didn't copy paste the original, but the modified and deleted the extra lines. Thank you.

Comment: And I tried this out too, using a lexicon.py file and changed the import. Works as well. Muchas.